# Can I add a meteor package for a single platform

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I would like to add a single package [(ground:db)](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) to my meteor project but it will only be used in the cordova builds. So it would be nice if it wasn't cluttering up the assets on the web builds.

Is this possible?

I've checked the docs for meteor add but no joy there.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if there is a way to limit the package code being included in certain builds to reduce the code that is downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a new package to do this, heres a quick step by step way to do what you want:

1) If you don't have a `packages` folder in your project, create one

2) Create a directory so you have `packages/mobileapp`

3) In the `mobileapp` directory create a `package.js` with the following contents

```
Package.describe({
   summary: "For cordova use only",
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
    if(api.versionsFrom) api.versionsFrom("METEOR@1.0");

    api.use(['ground:db'], ['web.cordova']);
});
```

Then in your meteor's root directory you can run

```
meteor add mobile
```

This will ensure that the `ground:db` package is only added in your `cordova` builds. No source code at all from it will be included on the web builds.

You can also add files to the package in the `Package.on_use` method using [api.add_files](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_addFiles) with `web.cordova` as the architecture so that only the files you list here will be included in cordova builds but not web app builds.

The advantage to doing this over using `if(Meteor.isCordova)` is that you won't be including any unnecessary source code in your web builds, this can sometimes make your web app

Comment: Yea this is what I've done as mentioned above. Btw you don't have to manually create the package files & directory. You can just run:
`meteor create --package mobile`

Comment: @jms301 Nice tip, thanks. Sorry the answer seems similar to the other one, I was typing it my electricity got cut so I decided to post it anyway when it came back. The main difference is you don't have to alter the ground:db package & it becomes a bit easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db/blob/connection-driver/package.js) is the package.js from ground db.

Trying replacing the `api.addFiles` to this.

```
api.addFiles([
    'groundDB.client.js',
    'wrap.collection.js',
    'wrap.eventemitter.js',
    'wrap.proto.eventemitter.js',
    ], 'web.cordova');
  api.addFiles('groundDB.server.js', 'web.cordova');
});
```

Check this extra information from this [Github Question](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2917).

```
Inside a package today you can do:

api.addFiles('foo.js', 'web.cordova'): includes foo.js in only Cordova/Phonegap builds.
api.addFiles('bar.js', 'web.browser'): includes bar.js in only browser builds.
api.addFiles('baz.js', 'web'): includes baz.js in all client builds.
and also:

api.use('foo:bar', 'web.cordova'): using the package API in only Cordova/Phonegap builds.
api.use('foo:bar', 'web.browser'): using the package API in only browser builds.
api.use('foo:bar', 'web'): using the package API in all client builds.
```

Check if it works.

Comment: Ah nice, yea I'm using the features as package pattern anyway so I can just update my packages.js files to limit to Cordova